# Error when trying to call rest API in angular 7 with HttpClient

Tags: javascript, angular, httpclient

I am trying to call a rest-api from my angular code:-

**service.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AssociationService {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getAll() {
    return this.http.get<AssociationResponse>('https://abc/getassociation');
  }
}
```

**component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.associationService.getAll()
          .subscribe((data: any) => this.associations = data,
            error => {},
            () => {});
      }

    constructor(private associationService: AssociationService) {}
```

**AssociationResponse.ts**

```
export class AssociationResponse extends APIResponse {
  constructor(message: string, status: string) {
    super(message, status);
  }
  public associations: Association[];
}

export interface Association {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  adminName: string;
  email: string;
  url: string;
  contactNumber: string;
  password?: string;
}
```

**APIResponse.ts**

```
export class APIResponse {
  message: string;
  status: string;
  constructor(message: string, status: string) {
    this.message = message;
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
providers: [AssociationService, 
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true},
    {provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true},

    // provider used to create fake backend
    fakeBackendProvider,
  ],
```

The API call gives me the below error :-

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (error.interceptor.ts:19)
```

message is one of the attribute of Json response.But if it call the API in the below way it works fine.

```
this.httpClient.get<AssociationResponse>
    ('https://abc/getassociation')
      .subscribe(response => {
        this.associations = response.associations;
      });
```

Can anyone please let me what am i doing wrong.

Comment: have you declare your service on providers on app.module.ts?

Comment: @Tzimpo : Yes I have included in the service in app.module.ts

Comment: if you create a service with `{ providedIn: 'root' }` there is no need to add it in `providers` in `app.module`. Its registered as singleton service for the whole app. https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: @Sunny can you create a stackblitz to test it there?Try to add brackets on your subscribe on ngOnInit.((data: any) => {this.associations = data}

Comment: in your service what you have defined `constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }` or `constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }` ?

Comment: @piyushjain - httpClient

Comment: `error => () => {},` should be this `error => {},`

Comment: @piyushjain - after making the change u suggested. I am getting an error, I have updated my question with the details.

Comment: ok...can you please provide stackblitz url ?